# Why can't I scroll my list when I have carousels above it?

Tags: arrays, flutter, dart

I created a homepage containing horizontal carousels, and under this carousel I created a vertical scrolling list,
I don't know why, but my vertical list doesn't scroll, can anyone have any idea why? I would like vertical scrolling to scroll through everything, both carousels and lists

my code:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return StoreConnector<AppState, OrdersScreenProps>(
      converter: (store) => mapStateToProps(store),
      onInitialBuild: (props) => this.handleInitialBuild(props),
      builder: (context, props) {
        List<Order> data = props.listResponse.data;
        bool loading = props.listResponse.loading;

        Widget body;
        if (loading) {
          body = Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
          );
        } else {
          body = 
              Container(
                height: 150.0,
                child: ListView.builder(
                  scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                  itemCount: data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                    Order order = data[i];
                    return GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        props.getOrderDetails(order.id);
                        Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.orderDetails);
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                        width: 210.0,
                        child: Stack(
                          alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Positioned(
                              bottom: 15.0,
                              child: Container(
                                height: 120.0,
                                width: 200.0,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                                  boxShadow: [
                                    BoxShadow(
                                      color: Colors.black26,
                                      offset: Offset(0.0, 2.0),
                                      blurRadius: 6.0,
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                                    crossAxisAlignment:
                                        CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        order.title,
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 22.0,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                                            letterSpacing: 1.2),
                                      ),
                                      Text(
                                        order.city,
                                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                shrinkWrap: true,

                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                itemCount: data.length,
                separatorBuilder: (context, index) => Divider(),
                itemBuilder: (context, i) {
                  Order order = data[i];

                  return Card(
                      child: ListTile(
                    isThreeLine: true,
                    contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(25.0),
                    leading: CircleAvatar(
                        child: Icon(Icons.person),
                        foregroundColor: Colors.white,
                        backgroundColor: Colors.green),
                    title: Text(
                      order.title,
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(order.city),
                    trailing: Icon(Icons.arrow_forward_ios),
                    dense: true,
                    onTap: () {
                      props.getOrderDetails(order.id);
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, AppRoutes.orderDetails);
                    },
                  ));
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        }
        return Scaffold(
          // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(height * 0.15),
            child: AppBar(
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                  borderRadius:
                      BorderRadius.vertical(bottom: Radius.circular(10))),
              title: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
                height: 60.0,
              ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          body: SingleChildScrollView(child: body,),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
```

thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `physics: ClampingScrollPhysics()` or `physics: BouncingScrollPhysics()` on your second/vertical `ListView`

Also, your Widget `body` contains a `Container` and a `ListView.separated` widget. Wrap it in a column like below code:

```
Widget body = Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      height: 150.0,
      child: ListView.builder(

         //rest of your code

      ),
    ),
    ListView.builder(
       physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),

       //rest of your code

           ),
        ],
    );
```

Then add it to your `Scaffold`

```
return Scaffold(
  body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: body,
  ),
);
```